# Duplicate canvas animation in Android browser

Tags: android, css, animation, browser, canvas

I'm currently having an issue with a duplicate canvas animation only within the default Android browser running on v 4.1.1 on an Asus Transformer tablet.

The issue seems to arise when I set a child object of the canvas using objectName.x = 100 for example.

The animation will appear in the centre of the screen as expected but also at the top left of the screen which is unwanted.

There is no issue when running in Chrome and I've tested on a friends S4 and S3 with no issues, however I'm not sure what version OS they were running.

Has anyone ran into this issue before or can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if I remove overflow: hidden which I had applied to the html element, everything works fine.

It's a workaround but not ideal.